# I'm confused with the questions about python multiprocessing problem

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, terminate

```
    import multiprocessing
    import time
    import os
    
    def whoami(name):
        print("I'm %s, in process %s" % (name, os.getpid()))
    
    def loopy(name):
        whoami(name)
        start = 1
        stop = 1000000
        for num in range(start, stop):
            print("\tNumber %s of %s. Honk!!!" % (num, stop))
            time.sleep(1)
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        whoami("main")
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=loopy, args=("loopy",))
        p.start()
        time.sleep(5)
        p.terminate()
```

This code was from 'Introducing python' Book, 2nd versions by Bill Lubanovic. According to the book, when I run this code, the result occurs:

```
                 I'm main, in process xxxx
                 I'm loopy, in process ----
                     Number 1 of 1000000. Honk!
                     Number 2 of 1000000. Honk!
                     Number 3 of 1000000. Honk!
                     Number 4 of 1000000. Honk!
                     Number 5 of 1000000. Honk!
```

However, In my case, only 'Process finished with exit code 0' printed. I want to know which point of this code is wrong.

Comment: It works fluently in my computer, check the output configuration in your IDE

Comment: Okay, I will! Thanks for checking!